# Salutation in motivation letter for academic purpose

Tags: salutations

What salutation should be used except "Dear Sir\Madam," in motivation letter for enroll in Master or doctoral program?

"Dear person responsible for application review," ?

Also I read that ":" instead of "," must be used in salutations. Is it true?

Comment: reviewer, future employee...

Comment: "Dear Sir / Madam," with spaces and forward slash. This is not the time to try to be cute.

Comment: You can just start off with 'Greetings!', that's a better option when you are not sure whom you are addressing.

Comment: For formal letters, you should use *":"*. For informal letters, feel free to use *","* or *"—"* instead.

Comment: @acidblue: I might caution that using an exclamation point can come off as sounding a tad unprofessional in some situations.

Comment: @Alex - Yes, I tend to user exclamations everywhere, it's better if you avoid it in a salutation. Thanks :)

Comment: You might find some other useful answers in the salutation tag.